# Как можно упорядочить unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11

Требуется:
В цикле от 1 до N 
1) сгенерировать случайное число int в диапазоне [-2^30,2^30] 
2) найти его в unordered_set
3) вставить число в unordered_set
Посчитать сколько раз число было найдено в контейнере
Элементы в контейнере должны быть отсортированы по возрастанию.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вставлять элементы в unordered_set что бы элементы были упорядочены?
Что вообще значит упорядоченный unordered_set

В случае когда контейнер это vector все ясно, вот код

https://gist.github.com/TolyaTalamanov/36cd1c6bfdb4feba6cea4680e31fc013

Comment: Дети, нарисуйте красный автомобиль зеленым карандашом, но только чтоб он был синий...

Comment: Обращайтесь к тому, от кого задание получено. Возможно всё дело в банальной копипасте.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что упорядочивать unordered_set это глупость ?

Comment: да, он основан на хэш-функции,поэтому упорядочивать там нечего. Почитайте https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/128017/